# how can I add food id to my order?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

currently I am making a simple restaurant application by rails. Now, when I click on the button order (on the same row with the food item), it will lead me to the create new order page, but the thing is the order doesn't belong to any food because I don't know how to integrate the food id to the form of the order. Do I need to create another model like order_item to accomplish the task? Because later, I want to add the quantity for the food, and the ability for the user to order multiple food items at the same time(like a cart). By the way is there any gem that I can use in this situation? I looked at the spree gem, but I dont know whether  the gem is appropriate for my application?
Here are all the files:

[image: Menu Page]

**menu/drink.html.erb**:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <%= link_to "Breakfast", menu_breakfast_path, class: "nav-link" %>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <%= link_to "Lunch", menu_lunch_path, class: "nav-link" %>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <%= link_to "Dinner", menu_dinner_path, class: "nav-link" %>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <%= link_to "Drinks", menu_drink_path, class: "nav-link active" %>
  </li>
</ul>
<table class="table table-inverse sortable" >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><%= sortable "Name" %></th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th><%= sortable "Price" %></th>
      <th>Order</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <% @foods.each do |food| %>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><%= link_to food.name, food %></td>
        <td><%= food.description %></td>
        <td>$<%= food.price %></td>
        <td><%= link_to "Order", new_order_path, class: "btn btn-primary" %></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

**order/_form.htm.erb**:

```
<%= form_for(@order) do |f| %>
  <% if @order.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@order.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this order from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @order.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :coupon %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :coupon %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :username %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :phone %><br>
    <%= f.telephone_field :phone %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :address %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :address %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

orders_controller.rb:

```
def new
    @order = Order.new
  end
def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.save
        format.html { redirect_to order_path, notice: 'Order was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @order }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**order.rb**:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :foods
end
```

**food.rb**:

```
class Food < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :section
  belongs_to :order
end
```

Comment: The model should be order has many foods and the food belongs to order. You also don't setup the strong params in the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make some amends to your models and associations as a first step:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  has_many :order_items, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :products, through: :order_items
```

---

```
class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product
```

---

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :order_items
  has_many :orders, through: :order_items
```

You can interchange the model names as you see fit to suit your application.

You are probably going to get value looking at the `nested_form` gem, and exploring the use of `inverse_of` along with these associations, which can be used with `accepts_nested_attributes` to create a better experience.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, do you have any rails sample application that I can take a loot at or any tutorial links? I am just a beginner rails, so it would help me a lot if I can see the actual code or video. Have a nice day.

Comment: You can a look here - github.com/benhawker/point-of-sale-rails - but please note that this is far from being a best practice application.

Comment: Thank you, that is all I need. :)